# Choosing whether to Objective-C after learning C from "C Primer Plus"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I have development experience in C++, but I know there are some different aspects between C and C++. Now I am going to work on Objective-C. Is there any need to learn the book `C Primer Plus` before starting to write Objective-C code?

In addition, I have read the Objective-C programming book by Dave Mark. Now I plan to learn Cocoa on Mac and iOS development.

Answer (score 2):

Videos on lynda.com are very helpful. Specifically for iphone there is one good book called Beginning iphone Development by Mark laMarche

Comment: Mark **and** LaMarche. Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand **Pointers in C** effectively to tackle memory leak problems in future while doing iOS programming. When you have memory leaks, it means you are making memory locations pointed by pointers unhappy.

I prefer book by [Stephen G Kochan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321711394) for Objective C. For programming to iPhone, [Beginning iPhone 4 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X) is an excellent book.

Comment: thank you, os x platform is amazing, and I am ready to start my learning process.